# Flatlist is not scrollable

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a scrollable grid in my app but I am unable to scroll it . Tried everything but nothing is working .

```
return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <GridImage style={styles.imageThumbnail} imageUri={item} numColumns={3} />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap flatlist in a view and give height & width to it.

```
return (
    <View style={{ height:600,width:600 }}>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.data}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Country name={item} />}
        />
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the flex style proper on the parent components, there is no need to set a heigh and width style. That is why we use flexbox in the first place.

Wrap you render items with `<Pressable>`. Then `<FlatList>` scroll will work as expected.

There is a hint to that in the `<TouchableOppacity>` doc page. It says that it is "a wrapper for making views respond properly to touches". That probably means that oddly `Views` do not handle touches very well.

You can then use `Views` inside of `Pressable` though.